# How to redirect all requests to a specific domain name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-platform

I set up the SSL and custom domain name for my website on the App Engine.

It works perfectly fine: I can go to https://www.mywebsite.com and the page loads.

But I would like to make the following change.

If I go to mywebsite.com, I would to be redirected immediately to  https://www.mywebsite.com .

How can I do that ?

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish this using Apache/Nginx/Node/Client side JS/etc. Are you using `expressjs`? Need more info...

Comment: @RobM. express.js yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using expressjs then this code below will do it.

```
            app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {

            var checkHost = req.get('host').substring(0, 4);
            var condition = req.get('x-forwarded-proto') !== "https" || checkHost !== 'www.' || ( req.get('host').indexOf('www.') < 0);
            if (condition) {
                res.set('x-forwarded-proto', 'https');

                if (checkHost === 'www.' && ( req.get('host').indexOf('www.') >= 0)) {
                    res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
                }
                else {
                    res.redirect('https://www.' + req.get('host') + req.url);
                }
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            });
```

Comment: start of you routes file

Comment: the one that executes first. the first one that loads. are you requiring your route file one by one or reading whole directory?

Comment: its not neccassary though i mean the sequence. it will trigger when www.example.com/ is accessed

Comment: will this maintain the https for every page or do I need to add it before every request ?

Comment: you can remove the https part if your site is http

Comment: it will maintain https for every request. you dont need to do it for every request

Comment: it will trigger whenever any request is not from https and www is not there

Comment: i have updated my answer. This is exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

You can put this before you start adding routes. It will inspect the protocol of each request and redirect to the https version if it is coming in over http

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   if (req.protocol === 'http') {
      var host = req.host.replace('www.', '');
      return res.redirect('https://www.' + host + req.originalUrl);
   }
   next();
});
```

Note that if nginx/apache is handling the https stuff and forwarding to a non-https node server this will not suffice. You will need to look at headers in your conditional rather than `req.protocol` (something like the conditional that @Asif has)

Comment: Should I put that in my app.js ?

Comment: You need to put that in your whatever file you initialize express in, before you add any of your regular routes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also map your **naked domain** `mywebsite.com` to your GAE app, **in addition** to your `www.mywebsite.com`. Basically by repeating the procedure for [Adding a custom domain for your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-custom-domains-and-ssl) and selecting the naked domain at step 4 (emphasis mine):

> Continue to the next step of the *Add new custom domain* form and
>   select the custom domain you want to point to your App Engine app:
>
> - Specify the domain and subdomains you want to map.
>
>   **Note:** The naked domain and **www** subdomain are prepopulated in
>     the form.
>
>   - **A naked domain, such as `example.com`, maps to `http://example.com`.**
>   - A subdomain, such as `www`, maps to `http://www.example.com`.
> - Click **Submit mappings** to create the desired mapping.

Pros:

- simpler
- works for both standard and flex env apps, regardless of the app's language
- works for static content as well, unlike solutions based on app code changes

Cons:

- at least for the standard env apps there may be 2 redirects for `https` requests:

  - the 1st one is a 301 redirect to `http://www.mywebsite.com`
  - the 2nd one is a 302 redirect to `https://www.mywebsite.com`

Comment: That's exactly what I did. But there are no automatic redirects to the https counterparts :/

Comment: On standard env you'd just need the `secure: always` in `app.yaml`. But indeed that won't work on flex env...

Answer (score -1):

You need to create .htaccess file at root of your server for redirect.

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.urserver.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

using upper you can redirect to your domain